# What do I have to do to change the visuals of my audio visualizer?

Tags: audio, rust

I created my own audio visualizer in rust where I have the amplitude of each frequency stored as [f32; 3750].

I use [cpal](https://crates.io/crates/cpal) as audio backend with f32 audio samples, 2 channels and a 44.1khz sample rate.

I converted those samples using [rustfft](https://crates.io/crates/rustfft) like this:

```
pub fn convert_buffer(input_buffer: [f32; 3750]) -> [f32; 3750] {
    let mut planner = FftPlanner::new();
    let fft = planner.plan_fft_forward(3750);

    let mut buffer: Vec<Complex<f32>> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..3750{
        buffer.push(Complex {  re: input_buffer[i], im: 0.0 });
    }
    fft.process(&mut buffer[..]);

    let mut output_buffer: [f32; 3750] = [0.0; 3750];
    for i in 0..buffer.len() {
        output_buffer[i] = buffer[i].norm()
    }
    output_buffer
}
```

But when visualizing a 15.000hz sinus wave it looks like this:
[image: 15000hz sinus]

I dont really know anything about audio, so I dont know why it mirrors itself like this and why sub 500hz frequencies are pretty much cut off.

What do I have to do to make It behave in a way that It visualizes frequencies from 0hz to 20khz without this mirroring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is, in a sense, fine; what you are seeing are basic problems with *interpreting* the FFT, not with computing it.

---

First, the FFT is naturally a function from complex samples to complex samples. When you start with a real-valued input signal and convert it to complex by adding a zero imaginary component (or any other simple value, even copying the real `input_buffer[i]`), the output will always be a **mirrored spectrum**.

(Complex-valued signals can have arbitrarily asymmetric spectra, distinguishing positive frequencies from negative ones. This is not widely useful in audio, but it is fundamental to software-defined radio (SDR) applications of FFT and other DSP operations.)

In order to not get the mirroring, you must discard one half of the output. (It's slightly more efficient — though not 50%, if I recall correctly — to skip computing that half, but it doesn't look like `rustfft` offers that option.)

---

If you discard the *upper* half of the output (in terms of array indices), then you will find that the remaining “frequency bins” are arranged from 0 Hz up to 22.05 kHz. The library documentation notes this:

> Output Order
>
> Elements in the output are ordered by ascending frequency, with the first element corresponding to frequency 0.

Applications that do use the second half of the spectrum often swap the two halves, so that instead of a range of 0 Hz to [sampling frequency]/2, they go from −[sampling frequency]/2 to +[sampling frequency]/2. But since you're starting with a real, not complex, signal, this doesn't apply to you; I just mention it since you might have seen it in other plots that have 0 Hz at the center.

The drop-off which is visible in the center of *your* image corresponds to the high-pass anti-aliasing filter required in any digital signal processing. It should appear at the right edge once you've discarded the right half.

---

Finally, your code does not appear to have any *windowing* applied to the input signal. Windowing is a complex topic, but it is necessary to account for the fact that the FFT presumes a periodic signal which exactly repeats over the length of the input buffer, but we're actually feeding it a signal whose period is *not* an even division of the input buffer; windowing dampens the effects of this by attenuating the beginning and ending portions of the signal.

You should look up a standard [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) and apply it to your input data before the FFT; this should reduce the secondary peak you're observing.

Comment: Wow thank you, now it works pretty well. But I could not solve one problem where lower frequencies are not visible. Is there any recommended way of manipulating the horizontal size of frequencies relative to each other? like having an array like `[0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.125]` where each value represents the horizontal size of one quarter in the eq?

Comment: @BrunoWallner No, any such change would be making the plot _incorrect_ — though of course you can adjust it as you like if this is purely decorative. If the low frequencies are missing then it must be something about the input signal — in most audio signals, the low frequencies will tend to be _more prominent_ in a FFT plot.